# Webpack-dev-server not serving index.html

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

Now I'm using webpack to bundle and serving my html static page. But it not serving my index.html
Here is what I've tried:

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        hot: true,
        open: true,
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Hot Module Replacement',
            filename: 'index.html',
            template: 'src/index.html',
        }),
    ],
    optimization: {
        moduleIds: 'hashed',
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    chunks: 'all',
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

When I open browser I get:
HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found

Need helps

Comment: Have you figured out what the issue was in your case?